# Java LinkedList Node with addition and deletion

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I have a list of items and my program needs to display one item at a time with the option for user to go to the next or previous item.

Does Java have a LinkedListNode class, or is there a library with such implementation so I can traverse the list and append or remove elements at the same time? I am aware that Java has listIterator but I cannot modify the list when I am viewing it (encounter ConcurrentModificationException)

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList` exists, as does `java.util.ListIterator`.  I'm not 100% sure if you can add elements while iterating, but you can certainly *remove* them using iterators.  Depending on the scope of what it is you're trying to accomplish, it may be better to return a read-only copy of the list you want to show, and allow mutations (addition, subtraction) elsewhere.

Comment: Is this pagination in java?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can delete or add while using iterator, but I think if you iterated with a for loop you'd be able to use that current index to delete or add.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<string> theList = new ArrayList<>();
String input = "";
for (int i=0; i<t.size(); i++)
   {
   input = scanner.nextLine();
   if (input.equals("1")); //then delete
      theList.remove(i);
   else if(input.equals("2"))
      {
      theList.add(i, scanner.nextLine());
      }
   }
```